# How can I disable padding on table created by ASP.NET AJAX ValidatorCalloutExtender?

Tags: asp.net, css, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm working on a web application in ASP.Net C#, using AjaxControlToolkit ValidatorCalloutExtender controls on my field validators. The extender popups are being rendered like this:

[image: Broken popup]

(note the space betwen the error message box and the callout arrow). I know why this is happening; I have the form containing the controls I'm validating laid out in a table, and I have the following in my CSS for the form table:

```
.formTable td, .formTable th
{
    padding: 3px;
}
```

If I comment out the line `padding: 3px;` the popups look fine...but then my form layout looks bad.

So my question is this: Is there a way I can leave the padding on my form layout table but disable it on the popups that get rendered within the table?

**Edit**: Here's the complete CSS I have been playing with to override the styling of the validator callout.

```
.ajax__validatorcallout_popup_table
{
    /* display: none; */
    border: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    padding: 0px;
}

.ajax__validatorcallout_popup_table_row
{
    vertical-align: top;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: transparent;
    padding: 0px;
}

.ajax__validatorcallout_callout_cell
{
    width: 20px;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: right;
    vertical-align: top;
    border: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    padding: 0px;
}

.ajax__validatorcallout_callout_table
{
    height: 100%;
    border: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    padding: 0px;
}

.ajax__validatorcallout_callout_table_row
{
    background-color: transparent;
    padding: 0px;
}

.ajax__validatorcallout_arrow_cell
{
    padding: 8px 0 0 0;
    text-align: right;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-size: 1px;
    border: none;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.ajax__validatorcallout_callout_arrow_cell .ajax__validatorcallout_innerdiv
{
    font-size: 1px;
    position: relative;
    left: 1px;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-right: none;
    border-left: none;
    width: 15px;
    background-color: transparent;
    padding: 0px;
}

.ajax__validatorcallout_callout_arrow_cell .ajax__validatorcallout_innerdiv div
{
    height: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-right: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
}

.ajax__validatorcallout_error_message_cell
{
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: red;
    padding: 5px;
    border-right: none;
    border-left: none;
    width: 100%;
}

.ajax__validatorcallout_icon_cell
{
    width: 20px;
    padding: 5px;
    border-right: none;
}

.ajax__validatorcallout_close_button_cell
{
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: right;
    border-left: none;
}

.ajax__validatorcallout_close_button_cell .ajax__validatorcallout_innerdiv
{
    border: none;
    text-align: center;
    width: 10px;
    padding: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

**Edit**: Here's the ASP.Net rendered HTML for the popup table (sorry I have to post it as an image).

[image: Code for validator callout popup table]

Comment: Is there a class / id on the callout extender?

Comment: just add `position:relative; left:3px;` to the little corner thing, it's hard to say without seeing more info

Comment: When popup renders - does it have an ID in rendered HTML?

Comment: @vcsjones - I have been playing around with the CSS for the callout extender, but haven't gotten anywhere with it. At http://www.imaginativeuniversal.com/blog/post/2008/09/04/Styling-the-Validator-Callout-Extender.aspx, I read that if you want to change anything in its styling, you have to override everything because it doesn't render the nested classes properly otherwise. I'll add the overrides I've been playing with to the code above.

Comment: @Connor - Unfortunately that doesn't work because ASP.Net renders the popup as a table. I'll add an example of one of these rendered popups above.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter - It does: `ctl100_mainContent_wizNewIPR_vxRequestDescr_popupTable`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this should do the trick:

```
.popupclassname .formTable td, .popupclassname .formTable th {
    padding: 0px;
}
```

The trick is make the selector more specific than the general selector: More about how specifity works here: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Comment: Thank you! This wasn't *quite* what fixed it, but you pointed me in the right direction. I added `.formTable tr td .ajax__validatorcallout_popup_table tr td { padding: 3px 0 3px 0; }` to remove the space between the arrow and the message box, then I had to add some more padding inside the message box to make it look the way I wanted to.

Answer (score 1):

The quick way is to change your paddings from:

```
padding: 0px
```

to

```
padding: 0px !important
```

Comment: Using !important is generally regarded as a last resort solution and to be avoided whenever possible. One should only really use it when you have no control over the main stylesheet and need to resort to drastic measures to make your rule more specific. Often !important is KLUDGE solution to badly coded CSS